# Bash: скрипт не правильно определяет доступность директории

Tags: bash, linux

bash-скрипт запущен с правами рута.
Данное условаие всегда идёт по ветке 1, хотя директория (/var/cache/my/2014/07/11/17) существует.
Не могу понять в чём дело.

```
if [ ! -d "$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour" ]
                then
                        #ветка 1
                else
                        #ветка 2
```

**UPDATE**
А вот так работает правильно(ветка 2)

```
       ppp="$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour"
       if [ ! -d $ppp ]; then
               #ветка 1
       else
               #ветка 2
```

Comment: я бы чуточку выше распечатал бы значение

    echo "$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour"

С другой стороны, можно убрать ! и обменять ветки местами.

Comment: Значения правильные, т.е. адрес построился верно.  
Менять ветки из-за ерунды этого не гут.

Answer (score 2):

[[@zenith](/users/5568/zenith)](/users/5568/zenith), а напечатайте

```
echo $ppp
```

и

```
echo "$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour"
```

просто интересно, как это может быть?

**Обновление**

Бред какой-то...

Попробовал у себя (только вместо /var взял /tmp, задал все перменные cur_... и source_file_dir=/tmp/cache/my, сформировал `ppp`, в `if`

```
  if [ ! -d "$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour" ]
```

)

и все работает:

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./s.sh
ppp: /tmp/cache/my/2014/07/11/11
str: /tmp/cache/my/2014/07/11/11
ветка 1
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ mkdir -p /tmp/cache/my/2014/07/11/11
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./s.sh
ppp: /tmp/cache/my/2014/07/11/11
str: /tmp/cache/my/2014/07/11/11
ветка 2
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Comment: Скопировал прмя из отладчика  

    echo $ppp # /var/cache/my/2014/07/11/17
    echo "$source_file_dir/$cur_year/$cur_month/$cur_day/$cur_hour" #/var/cache/my/2014/07/11/17

Comment: @zenith отладку делайте лучше не через echo а используя -x, например:

    #!/bin/bash -x
    a="test \"";
    echo $a;

Answer (score 0):

- Попробуйте без "`!`" - поменять местами
- Попробуйте с "`;`" и "`then`" в одной строчке с условием
- Какая версия bash?
- Во втором случае "`$ppp`" - без кавычек - может в этом ошибка?
- Выложите минимальный скрипт на pastebin - дайте попробовать нам на наших bash-ах

Comment: @Speakus для такого рода рекомендаций, стоит использовать комментарии. Вот вам минус :)

Comment: То есть на мое искренне желание вам помочь - вы решили поставить мне минус? Да еще и проигнорировали мои вопросы по теме? Ну тогда вам за это только плюс!

Comment: @Speakus уточняющие вопросы лучше правда в комментарии писать.